# What power I actually get as a Cleric with Fire domain?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, alignment, domains

> Turn or destroy water creatures as a good cleric turns undead. Rebuke, command, or bolster fire creatures as an evil cleric rebukes undead. Use these abilities a total number of times per day equal to 3 + your Charisma modifier. This granted power is a supernatural ability.

Being a good cleric (actually, a neutral cleric who channels positive energy), would I get both abilities or just the first one?

If I get both, is the daily limit shared?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get both, and the number of uses is shared. That is what "a total number of times per day" means.

Your alignment has no bearing on this ability; you turn [water] creatures *as* (I.e. Using the same mechanics as) A good cleric turns undead. You are not a good cleric and this ability does not turn undead.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that being a good or evil cleric has no effect on things here, since the question specifically mentioned that factor. +1 anyway.